# RecyclerView.Adapter - getItemId() - Stable IDs in your adapter MUST BE unique and SHOULD NOT change

Tags: android-recyclerview

Android Studio 3.1.4, Java 1.8

My pojo (first version) :

```
public class Product {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private long merchantId;
    private String name;
   // getter and setter
}
```

In my RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
 @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        Product product = (Product) getItem(index);
        return product.getId();
    }
```

And this work fine.
But I update my pojo like this:

```
public class Product {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String uniqueId;
    private long id;
    private String name;
   // geter and setter
}
```

And now I get error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime( 3937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID. Stable IDs in your adapter MUST BE unique and SHOULD NOT change.
 ViewHolder 1:ViewHolder{42b085c8 position=1 id=45, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 not recyclable(1)} 
 View Holder 2:ViewHolder{431beef0 position=0 id=45, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1} android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{4250a110 VFED.V.. ......ID 0,0-720,866 #7f090214 app:id/sortRecyclerView}, adapter:com.myprojectui.adapter.PreviewShoppingBaseSortAdapter@430d1f80, layout:android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager@42f4fe70, context:myproject.customer.ui.MainActivity@421f4460
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.handleMissingPreInfoForChangeError(RecyclerView.java:3826)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3(RecyclerView.java:3751)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3421)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1699)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
```

As you can now my private key is field **uniqueId** and it has type **String**.
The field **id** not unique any more. The field **uniqueId** is unique.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you haven't set `YourAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)` on the adapter assigned to your recyclerview.